# React Native Tab View : displaying empty screen when Tabview element is wrapped / nested within View

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabview, react-native-tab-view

I am using `'react-native-tab-view'` library in my code. Link here: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) / [github](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view#readme).

Here is a [basic example code in snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@satya164/react-native-tab-view-quick-start)- that can run on Web.

Now the issue is- if I want to display a Header text above `<Tabview/>` tag, it shows nothing. Even if I just wrap the `<Tabview/>` within a `<View></View>` like this below snippet, it shows an empty screen, even without any error.

```
<View>
  <TabView .... />   /*Shows empty screen*/
</View>
```

Here is an example code screenshot with output, from [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@avisek-nspire/react-native-tab-view-quick-start) with nested `<Tabview/>`, **running in Android device**:

[image]

Kindly suggest how to achieve that. Not sure what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the `TabView` was rendered inside a parent `ScrollView` ... removing the parent scroller resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have to use `<View style={{flex:1}}> Tab code </View>`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions and i had the same issue, in my case i had to downgrade the react-native-tab-view to 3.1.1
and the react-native-pager-view to 6.0.1 it was ^6.2.3
my react-native version is 0.72.4

just update those two in your package.json, npm install and cd ios && pod install, it worked like a charm

```
"react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",

"react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
```

hope it helps someone cause i did so much digging and nothing worked for me besides this solution