# react-native-tab-view is not visible , not displayed on screen or not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-tab-view

react-native-tab-view is not visible , not displayed on screen or not working because of the  flex: 1 styling , we have to give flex: 1 styling inside parent view , otherwise it not displayed on screen .

for reference : https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/blob/main/example/src/CustomTabBarExample.tsx

solution :-

1st ex. with default tab bar -

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

import { TabView, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

const BookingScreen = () => {

const layout = useWindowDimensions();

const FirstRoute = () => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }} /> // here also writing flex: 1 is mandatory
);

const SecondRoute = () => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }} /> // here also writing flex: 1 is mandatory
);



const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
const [routes, setRoutes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
    { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
]);

const renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
    // first: FeedbackScreen,
    // second: ProfileScreen,
});





return (
    <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // wrtie flex: 1 inside parent view its mandatory ***



            <TabView
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                renderScene={renderScene}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
            />

            


        </View>

    </>
)
}

export default BookingScreen
```

2nd ex. with custom tab bar -

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

import { TabView, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';


const BookingScreen = () => {


const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
const [routes, setRoutes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
    { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
]);



const _renderTabBar = props => (
    <TabBar
        {...props}
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
        tabStyle={[styles.tab, { height: 38, maxHeight: 38, minHeight: 38, padding: 0 }]}
        labelStyle={[styles.label, { color: colors.text, }]}
        indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
    />
);



return (
    <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // giving flex:1 inside parent view is mandatory


            

            <TabView
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}

                renderTabBar={_renderTabBar}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                renderScene={({ route }) => {
                    switch (route.key) {
                        case 'first':
                            return (<>
                                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }} > // giving flex:1 is mandatory otherwise content will not shown
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>sadfghjkljhgfcgvhbj</Text>
                                </View>

                            </>);

                        case 'second':
                            return (<>
                                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }} > // giving flex:1 is mandatory otherwise content will not shown
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>sadfghjkljhgfcgvhbj</Text>
                                </View>

                            </>);
                        default:
                            return null;


                    }
                }}
            />



        </View>

    </>
)
}

export default BookingScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    label: {
        fontWeight: '600',
        // fontSize: 12,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        // color: Colors.text,
        // minWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width < 375 ? '100%' : '60%'
    },
})
```

Comment: try this solution for any one having this issue it might work https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652281/7282042

Answer (score 15):

For future readers, a common problem is that the parent container doesn't have a defined height.

You must set the **parent container height**, for instance:

```
<View style={{height: "100%"}}> //or flex: 1
    <TabView
        navigationState={{ index, routes }}
        renderScene={renderScene}
        onIndexChange={setIndex}
        initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue where my `TabView` was located within a ScrollView. Interestingly, it operated without issue when executed on `Expo Web`, but the same could not be said for an Android emulator or device. The solution I found was to remove the TabView from the ScrollView. That's all there was to it - if your TabView is contained in a ScrollView, you should extract it from there, or encase it in a different container that utilizes a different `flexDirection`.

Comment: what's as good replacement for TabView though? or are you saying abandon Tabs?

Comment: - @howard .. I meant, TabView should not be a direct child of ScrollView, I didn't mean replace TabView

Comment: doesn't the functionality change then?

Answer (score 0):

Remove parent container will fix this problem.

```
return (
            <TabView
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                renderScene={renderScene}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
            />
)
```